# Remove subject field from comments

Tags: 7, forms, comments

Is it possible to remove the subject field on comment forms?  I find it to be kind of useless and redundant, since the subject of the comment is usually the title of the article being read, at least for me anyway.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can turn it off in the UI at `admin/structure/types/manage/type-name` with the "Allow comment title" checkbox:

[image]

Comment: Seems like they should rename "title" to "subject"... it would be less confusing.  Thanks.

Comment: In my case it is not possible to remove comment subject. Is it possible that there is a problem with other modules or after publishing some nodes this feature doesn't function?

Answer (score 2):

There I have found some solutions to this question.

**Option 1:**

[How to disable comment titles in Drupal 7](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/drupal-7/comments/disable-comment-titles). This is so easy and good tutorial to simply hide the subject(title) of comment through user interface.

**Option 2:**

You can also use the *hook_preprocess_comment()* in `template.php` file of your current active theme. This is really cool snippet, you can also some other options ie. comment-reply, comment-delete or comment-edit etc.

```
function bartik_preprocess_comment(&$vars) {
  $vars['submitted'] = $vars['created'] . ' — ' . $vars['author'];
  switch( $vars['node']->type ){
    case 'macine-name-of-node-type':
      $vars['title'] =FALSE;
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
//get comment by node id
$comment->nid = $nid;
//get form by form name
$form = drupal_get_form('comment_form', $comment); 
//hide subject in form
hide($form['subject']);
//check comment form
print render($form);
```

Comment: I don't get it ...

Comment: Hi Vivec, 4 lines of code are not really an answer. Can you explain where to place these lines? What function or hook?